# How to debug package use conflict in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osgi

When using cxf in an eclipse rcp application you get errors like:
Package uses conflict: Import-Package: ...myservicepackage; version="5.3.0.SNAPSHOT"

In this case my service interface and types used annotations which where exported by the system bundle and one of the dependencies of cxf. So while I solved it in this case the error reporting in eclipse is very bad. The package shown in the error is not the root of the error but just the top level package where it surfaces.

Is there any way to let eclipse rcp or in general equinox report some more details here?
So for example it would help to see which duplicate packages are in the conflict and which bundles export them.

Comment: The error reporting in Felix is much better for uses-constraints. I appreciate this probably doesn't help you much if you have to run an RCP app...

Comment: Yes unfortunately this will not help. Can you give me a hint where in the code of felix the better diagnostics happen? Perhaps I can create a patch for equinox to improve the reporting there too.

Comment: It happens in the Resolver. Probably better to wait for Luna (Equinox 4.4 I think?) which will be based on the Felix resolver also. Tom Watson gave a talk at EclipseCon about the major changes coming in Equinox, see http://www.eclipsecon.org/2013/sessions/equinox-improving-and-evolving-core-framework

Comment: Cool presentation. Looks like there are some big changes ahead :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found following link to be useful to resolve one such instance. You could also give a try.

http://blog.springsource.org/2008/11/22/diagnosing-osgi-uses-conflicts/